# iphone xml handing

Tags: iphone

I want my app to read a XML via internet.

Also I want to keep the previously download xml so next time I may not need to download again until certain hours is passed or whatever period of time according to settings.

Do you recommend me to download it first and store locally before process it? Or should I process it while downloading (with libxml2 I guess)?

What do you usually with apps using remote XML?

Targeting 3.0 devices btw.

Answer (score 0):

The `libxml2` library has a SAX parser that you can use to process XML as it comes in, to reduce memory usage. If you use the DOM parser, you have to store the entire document in memory, which can be an issue for iPhone and iPod Touch devices.

Take a look at Apple's [XMLPerformance](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/XMLPerformance/index.html) sample application, which demonstrates how to use the SAX parser. It's a bit more complicated than the DOM approaches, but it will be faster and use less memory.

Comment: The reason that I want to download the xml first is that I think it's a way to prevent any malformed xml crashing the app or messing all content. Parsing on the fly with libxml2 seems unable to prevent that.

Comment: Then the specification of your application will require you to use a DOM parser, which libxml2 also supports, among other frameworks and wrappers.